# How to set wordpress Site as child to independent html site?

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an html website on lets say [www.itsNotMatter.com](http://www.itsNotMatter.com) And Im having a wordpress site on [www.itsNotMatter.com/blog](http://www.itsNotMatter.com/blog)

I only linked together the 2 sites so it look like the same site to the users.  but google defines it as 2 seperate websites and it make a hard time for me on google search.

how to fix the problem ? tnx

Comment: are you using different GTM or google analytics code on both sites?
and is it a subdomain like blog.itsnotmatter.com on your hosting?

Comment: Please elaborate on “google defines it as 2 seperate websites”